# MySQL SELECT query returning for integer and integer + string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table name  `students`

```
uid  |  name
-----+-------
10   |  John
11   |  Smith
```

**Data types : **

```
uid  int(11)
name varchar(256)
```

**My query :**

```
SELECT name FROM students WHERE uid = '10'
```

**Returns** : `John`

**My 2nd query :**

```
SELECT name FROM students WHERE uid = '10someChar'
```

**Returns** : `John`

Why the second query returns John ?

Comment: include create script for your table

Comment: length for int(11) ???

Comment: @phpsessionid include create script for the table `students`

Comment: What is create script ?

Comment: `create table students(...)....`

Comment: Q: Why would you want to use characters inside your WHERE clause if you know your `uid` column is an `int`? I don't see why you would want to do that, can you give me an example why, and why you would want to know how to avoid coercion? @phpsessionid - If I knew the reason, I would most likely be able to give you an answer. Do add the @ symbol in front of my name when replying; it will be easier for me to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The uid column is integer, and the value you pass in the where clause is first coerced into an integer... and most integer-conversion algorithms just grab the first set of digits they can find in the string (and ignore anything non-matching after it)... thus it finds 10 and ignores the rest

Comment: I know coercion happens in programming languages, does SQL also works the same way? Its a new info for me.

Comment: SQL is a programming language :)

Comment: Anyway to avoid coercion so that my second query should return empty rows. Possible?

Comment: That's a different question (to which I don't know the answer). I recommend you ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa.

It is also possible to convert a number to a string explicitly using the CAST() function.

> [Type Conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html)

take a read.

MySQL ever tries to return something - even if it's the wrong type, he'll cast automatically.

You should filter at PHP to validate your business rule.

Postgresql should throw a exception